# setting input type in dynamically created form is ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm clicking a button to bring up a bootstrap-modal with a dynamically created form inside. My problem is that the input fields are always treated as text, even though they are set to something else like select, readonly or number.

[Here you can see that the inputs have the right type-values, but the inputs are textfields anyway.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIUWk.png)

The form is created here (the outputs of console.log can be seen in the picture):

```
var data = "";

data += "<form name='altEditor-form' role='form'>";

for(var j = 0; j < columnDefs.length; j++){

  //Outputting input title and input.type 
  console.log(j + ": " + columnDefs[j].title + " - " + columnTypes[j].type)

  data += "<div class='form-group'><div class='col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-right' style='padding-top:7px;'><label for='" + columnDefs[j].title + "'>" + columnDefs[j].title + ":</label></div><div class='col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9'><input type='" + columnTypes[j].type + "'  id='" + columnDefs[j].title + "' name='" + columnDefs[j].title + "' placeholder='" + columnDefs[j].title + "' style='overflow:hidden'  class='form-control  form-control-sm' value='" + adata.data()[0][newaData[j].name] + "'></div><div style='clear:both;'></div></div>";
}

data += "</form>";
```

As you can see I set the input type like this:

```
<input type='" + columnTypes[j].type + "' ....
```

The form is then added to the modal here:

```
$('#altEditor-modal').find('.modal-body').html(data);
```

I can't make any sense of it. How is it possible that the type is completely ignored?

Comment: Why `pre`? I suspect this makes your markup inoperative.

Comment: readonly is not valid value to type.you can add "readonly" word.http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: @JeremyThille It looks as though he is trying to render the output of `data` as html

Comment: That's my point. Data is html, but the `pre` tag neutralises it and prevents the browser from interpreting the html inside.

Comment: @JeremyThille I am editing code created by someone else, so that is a remnant om his work. I tried changing it to `<div>` and also removing the tags all together, but the issue is the same.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for us to investigate and troubleshoot the issue further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting invalid `type` values, which the browser will in turn ignore treating those `input`s as `type="text"`: [`input`'s default `type` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

As of this post, valid `type` values for `input` elements are:

- `button`
- `checkbox`
- `color`
- `date`
- `datetime`
- `datetime-local`
- `email`
- `file`
- `hidden`
- `image`
- `month`
- `number`
- `password`
- `radio`
- `range`
- `reset`
- `search`
- `submit`
- `tel`
- `text`
- `time`
- `url`
- `week`

---

**`readonly` and `select` are not valid `type` values.**

Comment: I think i have a partial understanding of whats wrong. The readonly fields should not have `type='readonly'` but instead have the readonly attribute appended like `<input type="text" readonly>` - Is this correct?

Comment: @BaconPancakes Yes

Comment: @MageshKumaar thank you, and in terms of the `<input type="select">` it should be `<select id=""><option>OPTION1</option></select>` ?

Comment: @BaconPancakes, yes. [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms).